# TFS run local process

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs-2015, source-control-explorer

i have TFS express 2015 running on a local machine, i'm trying to get it to run a local process (a calculator window) as a second step after building.
i've tried command line, tried batch script and even tried powershell. the second step seems to go through just fine but no calculator is beeing opened.

is there anything i'm missing here? the TFS Express is installed on the same machine that runs visual studio.

please help!

Comment: I suspect the build agent is running as a service, and services can't run full UI processes.

Comment: Which kind of build are you using on TFS express 2015? XAML or vNext Build? At least this can be achieved by XAML build.

Answer (score 0):

For XAML build

If you want to open the local process (for example notepad） during Team Build, you need set your **Build Service running as Interactively**, launch your TFS Admin Console>>Build Configuration>>Build Service Properties>>Stop the service>>selected Run the Service Interactively.

Then you need to customize your build process template to create a [InvokeProcess activity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg265783.aspx#Activity_InvokeProcess). You can use the `InvokeProcess` activity to start a process (run a program) on the build server. This activity is essentially a wrapper over Start. In your `InvokeProcess` activity, set FileName = *“C:\Windows\notepad”*.

After above two steps, you can open the notepad during Team Build. When running your build definition, the notepad will be opened on your build agent machine, and your build keeps on running this open notepad activity. You need logon your build agent using your TFS Build Service account, then you will see the notepad be opened on build agent machine, after you close this notepad, your build will continue run next steps.